# Cannot open new tab for selenium in order to download a CSV file python

Tags: python, selenium

## Problem description

I am working on ubuntu 16.04.
I want to download CSV files from a website. They are presented by links. The moment I click on the link I want to open a new **tab** which will download the file. I used the solution provided in https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903.

[image: image description here]

---

## setup

```
 fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",download_path)
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv")

    # create a selenium webdriver
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
    # open QL2 website
    browser.get('http://live.ql2.com')
```

---

## code

```
 csvList = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("csv")
    for l in csvlist:
           if 'error' not in l.text and 'after' not in l.text:
               l.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL +'t')
```

Every Element l is represented as follows:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="9003fc6a-d8be-472b-bced-94fffdb5fdbe", element="27e1638a-0e37-411d-8d30-896c15711b49")>
```

---

## Question

Why am I not able to open a new tab. Is there something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are just making a new tab, not opening the link in a new tab.

Try using [ActionChains](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# create browser as detailed in OP's setup
key_code = Keys.CONTROL
csvList = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("csv")
for l in csvlist:
    if 'error' not in l.text and 'after' not in l.text:
        actions = webdriver.ActionChains(browser)
        # Holds down the key specified in key_code
        actions.key_down(key_code)
        # Clicks the link
        actions.click(l)
        # Releases down the key specified in key_code
        actions.key_up(key_code)
        # Performs the actions specified in the ActionChain
        actions.perform()
```

Comment: Were you doing the ActionChains inside the for loop? Also, I just want to check that control +click opens a new tab for you. Using OSX, Keys.COMMAND is needed, instead of Keys.CONTROL.

Comment: I am using it inside the for loop because i want to ignore CSV files that contains the words "error" and after "after". I using ubuntu i should use control?

Comment: Do you think it's because of Firefox? or it has nothing to do with that

Comment: Using Firefox shouldn't change it. I'm wondering if a new tab is opened for the download, but once the download starts Firefox closes it. This is behavior when using both Firefox and Chrome normally.

Comment: no. No new tab is opened at all. I remain on the same page

Comment: **if(actions.key_down(key_code)):
                           print "control key pressed"** shows me that the control key was pressed

Comment: Selenium does not automatically move to the new tab when it is opened. It requires the user to explicitly change the window focus with `browser.switch_to_window(tab)` where `tab` is the index of the tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146445/discussion-between-brydenr-and-hani-gotc).